# How to remove auto-generated fields from DRF - Swagger UI

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I've a model where few fields are auto-generated. How do I hide those fields from the Swagger UI during POST request? Following is the example:-

```
class ModelX(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()
    c = models.CharField()
    d = models.CharField()
```

Below is my serialzer:-

```
class Serializerx(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelX
        fields = '__all__
```

In the above model, fields `b` and `d` are auto generated from my code, which means these fields are not required as an input from the user.

If I add `b` and `d` as read-only fields, then I wont be able to create an object with these values.

How do I hide some attributes from the payload request.? Somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973840/hidden-fields-in-swagger-ui)

Answer (score 0):

In the Meta class you can specify which fields you don't want to display:

```
class Serializerx(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelX
        exclude = ('a','c','or_whatever_field_you_want_to_exclude')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just specify which fields you want to be displayed.

```
class Serializerx(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = ModelX
    fields = ['a','c',]
```